# Reset camera orientation?

Tags: camera

Hi so I shrunk my mesh down a great deal from 20 meters in height to about 2 and now the camera orientation is really weird. How do I reset it to move around my shrunk mesh instead of still behaving like it is moving around the larger one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the mesh and press the period key on the Numpad.