# Name of command to reset 3D-view (camera)

Tags: 3d-view

I am on a Mac.  My 3D-view (camera) is [not panning and zooming correctly anymore](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ToGEYQxWtAY).

I know [I need to press `numpad .`](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/167039/83475) (the period key on the numpad).  I do not have a number pad.

I know I can get around not having a numpad by [remapping the key](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/89490/83475).  However I do not know what the name of the command is that will reset the 3D-view.

I searched for "numpad ." and tried remapping several of the available commands to <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>.  But when I select an object and then issue that key combo, my 3D-view does not change.

[image]

Comment: Try "Frame Selected" in the _3D View_ (because your problem is in the _3D Viewport_, everything else is in other parts of Blender). If that doesn't help, instead of remapping the key try the shortcut Shift+C.

Comment: Thanks @GordonBrinkmann .  I've post this as an answer but please feel free to post it and I'll accept yours and delete mine.

Comment: That's okay, go ahead. I think you can accept your own after 24 or 48 hours.

Answer (score 0):

The third "Frame select" under 3D View is the one you want to remap.  The others might work as well but I did not test them.